# The flow of Killing vector field is an isometry-proof verification

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, isometry

I am trying to show if given a flow $\Phi$ of a Killing vector field $X$, then $\Phi_{s}$ is an isometry for all $s$ belongs to real number. The definition of Killing vector field is $X$ is Killing vector field if its's Lie derivative to metric tensor is zero. Then I have come up an argument:

Since $X$ is a Killing vector field, it's Lie derivative to metric $g$ is zero. That is, $\Phi^{*}_{s}g=g$ for all $s$ by definition of Lie derivative. Then  $\Phi_{s}$ is isometry. Q.E.D.

Is the above argument works, if not, what is the problem?

Comment: Generally speaking, the push forward of tensor is not so used.  Is it pull-back $\Phi_{s}^*g$ instead $\Phi_{s*}$? In your TeX, the pull back looks like a push forward.

Comment: Yes, it is a pullback, I will edit it

Comment: I vote that your argument is correct. Sorry, I misunderstand. One parameter transorm is diffeomorphic, so, the push forward is also correct. So, $(\Phi_s)_* g_{    \Phi_{-s}(p) } = g_p$ for all $p$ in a manifold and sufficiently small $s \geq 0$.

Comment: The only thing I would ask is how do you conclude from Lie derivative being zero that $\Phi_s^*g = g$ for all $s$? Of course it is relatively simple to deduce this from the definition $\mathcal{L}_Xg = \dfrac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s=0}\Phi_s^*g$ (I'm just saying that I don't think it is as obvious as you make it sound... but if this is an obvious fact for you, then fine, your proof otherwise is right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the main point of the proof i.e. the reason that $\Phi_s^* g = g$ is missing in your proof. We can fill that gap by observing that it follows from the uniqueness of solutions of the equation:

$\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s = 0} \Phi_s^* g = 0 $

with initial condition $\Phi_0^* g = g$.